# Jarsigner - Signer certificate not yet valid (AIR Application code signing to publish on Google Play)

Tags: air, osx-snow-leopard, google-play, keytool, jarsigner

I have created a `Self-Signed Certificate` in `Mac OS` using `Keychain Access` to be used as a certificate for my `AIR Application`. After exporting a release build for my app in `Flash Builder 4.6`, I have verified my `apk` using `jarsigner` by executing the following command:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs myapp.apk
```

then, the following message was returned:

```
jar verified.

Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate is not yet valid.
```

is it ok to publish this app on `Google Play`?
if possible, how to validate my self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root cause for my problem: since `Google Play` requires a certificate to be expired after `October 22, 2033`, i have changed my system date to an advance date.

Valid value for the validity period of `Keychain Access` certificate assistant is 20 years so if I'll create a new certificate, it will expire on June 26, 2033 which fails to achieve the requirement.

```
A validity period for an X509 certificate is the number of days the certificate
is valid from the time it is issued. Certificates issued by Certificate Assistant
have a maximum validity period of 20 years.
```

upon using this certificate for the code signing of my air application, Google Play prompts an error upon uploading the apk

```
Upload failed

You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. 
You need to sign your APK with a certificate that is currently valid.
```

[Learn more about signing.](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

So i created a new certificate using `keytool` by executing the following commands:

```
$ keytool -keystore cert.jks -genkeypair -alias cert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 \
  -validity 18250 -dname 'CN=cert,OU=org,O=org,L=location,ST=state,C=PH'

$ keytool -keystore cert.jks -exportcert -alias cert \
  | openssl x509 -inform der -text

$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.jks -destkeystore cert.p12 \
  -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```